# Show custom Attribute with SCP for Configurable Product Magento

Tags: magento

I want to add values from Custom Attribute to short description of Configurable Product in Magento. I am using SCP module to show dynamically short description, title and price for this one regarding to "Associated Simple Products ". The price, Title and short description work fine but it not change the long description and not show the custom Attributes associated to Simple product. 
Can some body help me with this problem? I need some indication how can I do that?
I think that I can do it on the original file configurable.php from SCP (Simple Configurable products) module that I attached to this post but I am not sure.
Thank you in advance.

```
public function getJsonConfig()
{
    $config = Zend_Json::decode(parent::getJsonConfig());

    $childProducts = array();

    //Create the extra price and tier price data/html we need.
    foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
        $productId  = $product->getId();
        $childProducts[$productId] = array(
            "price" => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($product->getPrice())),
            "finalPrice" => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($product->getFinalPrice()))
        );

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_name')) {
            $childProducts[$productId]["productName"] = $product->getName();
        }
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_description')) {
            $childProducts[$productId]["description"] = $product->getDescription();
        }
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_short_description')) {
            $childProducts[$productId]["shortDescription"] = $product->getShortDescription();
        }

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_attributes')) {
            $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes');
            $childProducts[$productId]["productAttributes"] = $childBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->toHtml();
        }

        #if image changing is enabled..
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_image')) {
            #but dont bother if fancy image changing is enabled
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_image_fancy')) {
                #If image is not placeholder...
                if($product->getImage()!=='no_selection') {
                    $childProducts[$productId]["imageUrl"] = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Remove any existing option prices.
    //Removing holes out of existing arrays is not nice,
    //but it keeps the extension's code separate so if Varien's getJsonConfig
    //is added to, things should still work.
    if (is_array($config['attributes'])) {
        foreach ($config['attributes'] as $attributeID => &$info) {
            if (is_array($info['options'])) {
                foreach ($info['options'] as &$option) {
                    unset($option['price']);
                }
                unset($option); //clear foreach var ref
            }
        }
        unset($info); //clear foreach var ref
    }

    $p = $this->getProduct();
    $config['childProducts'] = $childProducts;
    if ($p->getMaxPossibleFinalPrice() != $p->getFinalPrice()) {
        $config['priceFromLabel'] = $this->__('Price From:');
    } else {
        $config['priceFromLabel'] = $this->__('');
    }
    $config['ajaxBaseUrl'] = Mage::getUrl('oi/ajax/');
    $config['productName'] = $this->getProduct()->getName();
    $config['description'] = $this->getProduct()->getDescription();
    $config['shortDescription'] = $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription();

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_image')) {
        $config["imageUrl"] = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image');
    }

    $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes');
    $config["productAttributes"] = $childBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml')
        ->setProduct($this->getProduct())
        ->toHtml();

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_image')) {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/change_image_fancy')) {
            $childBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_media');
            $config["imageZoomer"] = $childBlock->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/media.phtml')
                ->setProduct($this->getProduct())
                ->toHtml();
        }
    }

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('SCP_options/product_page/show_price_ranges_in_options')) {
        $config['showPriceRangesInOptions'] = true;
        $config['rangeToLabel'] = $this->__('to');
    }
    //Mage::log($config);
    return Zend_Json::encode($config);
    //parent getJsonConfig uses the following instead, but it seems to just break inline translate of this json?
    //return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
}
```